# QueryBuilder with filteredQuery and userquery in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using this piece of code to get data from elasticSearch:-

```
        QueryBuilder qb;
        if (query == null || query.trim().length() <= 0) {
            qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
        } else {
            qb = QueryBuilders.queryString(query.replaceAll(" ", " OR ").replaceAll(",", " AND ").replaceAll("!", " NOT "));

        }
        org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse searchHits =  node.client()
                .prepareSearch(name)
                .setQuery(qb)
                .addHighlightedField("file.filename")
                .addHighlightedField("content")
                .addHighlightedField("meta.title")
                .setHighlighterPreTags("<span class='badge badge-info'>")
                .setHighlighterPostTags("</span>")
                .addFields("*", "_source")
                .execute().actionGet();
```

This is working fine. But now i want filtered result with this query. Like we do in filteredQuery.

```
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/and-filter.html
```

How i can add FilterBuilder with queryBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    QueryBuilder qb;
    if (query == null || query.trim().length() <= 0) {
        qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
    } else {
        qb = QueryBuilders.queryString(query.replaceAll(" ", " OR ")
                .replaceAll(",", " AND ").replaceAll("!", " NOT "));
    }

    FilterBuilder fb = FilterBuilders.andFilter(.....);
    FilteredQueryBuilder fqBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(qb, fb);

    org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse searchHits = node
            .client()
            .prepareSearch(name)
            .setQuery(fqBuilder)
            .addHighlightedField("file.filename")
            .addHighlightedField("content")
            .addHighlightedField("meta.title")
            .setHighlighterPreTags("<span class='badge badge-info'>")
            .setHighlighterPostTags("</span>").addFields("*", "_source")
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Awesome. thank you. I didnt find this on elastic search and on google.